# Text displaying as bright yellow in terminal

Tags: macos

```
OS: Mojave 10.14.6
```

I am running into an issue, where a script I'm running, produces output in a terminal session, but the text color is a bright yellow, making it impossible to read. it is always, following a hashtag (#). For example:

```
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Card
 # ./spec/card_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

rspec ./spec/card_spec.rb:4 # Card has a type
```

Everything before the # is red, and everything after it is yellow

How do I control the terminal color display choices?

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, go to Preferences and click on Profile/Text. Click in the color box that says Text and also uncheck the box that reads Display ANSI colors.  See image below.

[image]